# Move terminal's cursor

Tags: ruby, terminal, cursor-position

I'm trying to move the cursor of the terminal to different coordinates, something equivalent to Pascal's `gotoxy`. Is there anything like that?

Comment: Is using [Ncurses](https://github.com/ruby/curses) an option?

Comment: I don't know anything about it so I guess it does

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences

Answer (score 2):

See [here](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html). The following example was tested in Windows `cmd` but must work in the other terminals too.

```
puts "+----------+"
puts "|          |"
puts "+----------+"
print "\033[2A\033[1C"
p = 0.5
10.times do
    print "#"
    sleep(p)
end
print "\033[2B"
puts
```

This will output a sort of a progress bar:

```
+----------+
|###       |
+----------+
```